# What is the largest subgroup of $GL^{+}(7,\mathbb{R})$ which smoothly retracts onto $G_2$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, exceptional-groups

There is a nice smooth retraction from $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ onto $\operatorname{U}(n)$, which can be explained using polar decomposition. There is an analogous one from $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ onto $\operatorname{O}(n)$. Both are "natural" from a Lie theoretic point of view (in a sense that shall not be made precise for now).

I am wondering what is the largest subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}^{+}(7,\mathbb{R})$ ('+' here just means with positive determinant) which smoothly retracts onto $\operatorname{G}_2$?

I have a strange feeling it could be $\operatorname{G}_2$ itself, because I don't think that one can split a $G_2$ structure into 2 independent pieces, one being a Riemannian inner product, and something else. For instance if one uses the usual $3$-form as one of the pieces, then the subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}^{+}(7,\mathbb{R})$ which preserves that $3$-form is $G_2$ itself (so that preserving that $3$-form implies preserving an inner product).

Comment: You really mean "retract" and not "retract by deformation"? I understand "smoothly retract" as the existence of a smooth map from the group $H$ (containing $G_2$) to $G_2$ that is the identity on $G_2$. By smooth retract by deformation, I would understand a map $f:H\times [0,1]\to H$ such that $f(g,t)=g$ for all $t$ and all $g\in G_2$, $f(-,0)$ is the identity and $f(-,1)$ maps into $G_2$.

Comment: I just want a smooth retraction, not deformation retraction, which has nice equivariance properties, if you will.

Comment: I guess $G_2$ stands for the compact form endowed with its standard 7-dim representation, right? Surely you can take the group generated by it and the (positive) scalar matrices. I guess that's it. Our mysterious group cannot have a unipotent radical (the $G_2$-rep is irreducible) and a reductive group is homotopically equivalent to its maximal compact subgroup.

Comment: OK. The list of subgroups of $SL_7$ containing $G_2$ is very short. The only compact ones are $G_2$ itself and $SO(7)$.  The non-compact ones are only $SL_7$ itself (unless the complex $G_2$ occurs as a 28-dimensional real subgroup here? I doubt this but this would not matter). So the question is only whether $SO(7)$ retracts.

Comment: @Uri Bader, I think you are right about the mysterious subgroup.

Comment: @YCor, I think that probably there cannot be a retraction from $SO(7)$ onto $G_2$. The comments you both wrote seem to confirm my suspicions, except for the fact that I had overlooked the scalar matrices. Thank you both!

Comment: @UriBader actually the fact that $G$ is homotopically equivalent to its maximal compact subgroups $K$ (and actually that $G$ is $K$-equivariantly homeomorphic to $K\times\mathbf{R}^{\dim(G/K)}$) is not specific to the reductive case: it holds for all Lie groups with finitely many connected components (Iwasawa/Mostow).

Comment: @Malkoun I'd be curious of an argument for $SO(7)$.

Comment: I don't have an argument yet. I will think about it.

Comment: $G_2$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to $S^3\times S^{11}$ and $SO(7)$ to $S^3\times S^7\times S^{11}$. I guess that the inclusion induces the natural split injection (but I haven't checked). Anyway it seems that at the level of rational homotopy there is no obstruction to a retraction $SO(7)\to G_2$.

Comment: Isn't ${\rm Spin}(7)/G_2$ a reductive symmetric space?

Comment: @VictorProtsak: its seems not (see the list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space).

Comment: $Spin(7)/G_2$ is the $7$-sphere. It is realized as the orbit through any nonzero point in the (8-dimensional real) spin representation of $Spin(7)$.

Comment: Thank you @Claudio Gorodski. Now the question is whether or not there is a smooth retract from $SO(7)$ onto $G_2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no retraction of $\mathrm{SO}(7)$ onto $\mathrm{G}_2$.  If such a retraction $\rho:\mathrm{SO}(7) \to \mathrm{G}_2$ existed, then the composition
$$
\mathrm{G}_2 \hookrightarrow \mathrm{SO}(7)\ {\buildrel{\rho}\over{\rightarrow}}
\ \mathrm{G}_2\,,
$$
would induce a composition of the homotopy group homomorphisms
$$
\pi_6\bigl(\mathrm{G}_2\bigr) \rightarrow \pi_6\bigl(\mathrm{SO}(7)\bigr)\ {\buildrel{\rho_*}\over{\rightarrow}}
\ \pi_6\bigl(\mathrm{G}_2\bigr)
$$
that was the identity.  However, according to M. Mimura, [*The homotopy groups of Lie groups of low rank*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250524375), J. Math. Kyoto Univ. **6** (1967), 131–176 (see the tables on page 132),
$$
\pi_6\bigl(\mathrm{G}_2\bigr)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_3
 \quad\text{while}\quad
\pi_6\bigl(\mathrm{SO}(7)\bigr)\simeq 0\,,
$$
so this is impossible.

Beyond this, though, I feel that the OP's given motivation for asking the question suggests that the issue of concern is not really whether $\mathrm{SO}(7)$ retracts onto $\mathrm{G}_2$.

The usual reason that one wants to retract $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ onto $\mathrm{U}(n)$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ onto $\mathrm{O}(n)$ is that these are the fundamental steps in the proof that a complex vector bundle over a paracompact base can always be given a unitary structure and a real vector bundle over a paracompact base can always be given an Euclidean structure (i.e., a positive definite inner product field).

The analogous question concerning $\mathrm{SO}(7)$ and its subgroup $\mathrm{G}_2$ would be whether every oriented $7$-plane bundle $E\to M$ endowed with an Euclidean structure can be given a $\mathrm{G}_2$-structure, i.e., whether there exists a 'definite' (i.e., a $\mathrm{G}_2$-defining) section of $\Lambda^3(E)\to M$.  Now, the answer to this question is a definite 'no'.  For example, let $M^7$ be any orientable-but-not-spinnable $7$-manifold, say $M^7 = \mathbb{CP}^2\times S^3$.  Then $E=TM\to M$ certainly has a $\mathrm{SO}(7)$-structure (defined by the orientation and any Riemannian metric on $M$), but, because $M$ is not spinnable (because $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not), its tangent bundle does not allow a structure reduction to $\mathrm{G}_2$.  (This is because $\mathrm{G}_2$ is simply-connected, so that any $7$-manifold whose tangent bundle has a reduction of structure to $\mathrm{G}_2$ would necessarily be spinnable.)

Thus, this particular problem does not motivate the retraction question.

The OP's other remark expressing doubts about whether a $\mathrm{G}_2$-structure can be split into two 'independent pieces' seems to be asking for an analog of what happens in complex and symplectic geometry, where one has the intersections
$$
\mathrm{U}(n) 
= \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})\cap \mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R})
= \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})\cap \mathrm{O}(n) 
= \mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R})\cap \mathrm{O}(n),
$$
so that one can think of a unitary structure as a combination of two 'independent' (but compatible) weaker structures.  The natural analog of this in the present context would be whether $\mathrm{G}_2$ can be expressed as the intersection of two (or more?) Lie subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(7,\mathbb{R})$ that properly contain $\mathrm{G}_2$.  The answer to this is a(n uninteresting) 'yes'.  There are only three connected Lie groups that lie strictly between $\mathrm{G}_2$ and $\mathrm{GL}^+(7,\mathbb{R})$, and they are
$$
\mathrm{R}^+{\cdot}\mathrm{G}_2,\quad \mathrm{SO}(7),\quad\text{and}
\quad \mathrm{R}^+{\cdot}\mathrm{SO}(7).
$$
Thus, the only nontrival way to do this is the uninteresting intersection
$$
\mathrm{G}_2 = \mathrm{R}^+{\cdot}\mathrm{G}_2 \cap \mathrm{SO}(7).
$$
Thus, the largest (connected) subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}^+(7,\mathbb{R})$ that retracts onto $\mathrm{G}_2$ is $\mathrm{R}^+{\cdot}\mathrm{G}_2$.

As a final argument as to why the retraction question seems to be irrelevant to the OP's apparent concerns, consider the analogous question of whether $\mathrm{SO}(2n)$ can be retracted onto $\mathrm{U}(n)$ for $n>1$.  It cannot, because, such a retraction $\rho$, if it existed in the form the OP desired, i.e.,
$$
\mathrm{U}(n)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{SO}(2n)\ {\buildrel{\rho}\over{\rightarrow}}
\ \mathrm{U}(n),
$$ 
where the composition is the identity on $\mathrm{U}(n)$, then the composition of the induced map on fundamental groups
$$
\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_2\to \mathbb{Z}
$$
would be an isomorphism, which is manifestly impossible.

Comment: Awesome answer :). Thank you so much Prof. Bryant. You read me correctly :). I was trying out a "dead alley" so to speak. I had realized that early on, though I did not have a proof that it was a "dead alley", but I had moved on, and succeeded in doing what I wanted to do. You are so smart, not just in Mathematics, but also in Psychology :). I will of course accept this brilliant answer, but please fix the small typo: you wrote $\mathbb{C}P^4$ instead of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ in the definition of $M^7$. Thank you.

Comment: @Malkoun:  You are welcome.  It was an interesting question, even though I felt that it was not the 'right' one.  I have fixed the typo; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I added a link to the article (which is open access).

Comment: @Malkoun, for future reference, you can make edits yourself (subject to approval of a higher-reputation user).

Comment: @RobertBryant, I was thinking about this post again. There is no retraction from $GL^+(7,\mathbb{R})$ to $G_2$. Thank you again for making this clear. Let us summarize this statement by saying that not every oriented basis of the imaginary octonions can be $G_2$-izable.

Comment: However, what conditions can one impose on a basis of the imaginary octonions, using the $7$-dimensional cross product, so that it is $G_2$-izable? In other words, can one define the largest submanifold of $GL^+(7,\mathbb{R})$ (I would guess defined using the $7$-dimensional cross product), which smoothly retracts onto $G_2$? Somehow, the basis must be placed in a "nice non-degenerate" way with respect to the cross product.

Comment: @Malkoun: I have no idea what $G_2$-izable means.

Comment: I have an idea, but it is not explicit. $SO(7)/G_2$ is $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^7$, which one can think of as $S^7$ quotiented out by the antipodal map. The octonionic cross product corresponds to a specific point on $S^7$ (up to the antipodal map). If you think of it as the North pole of $S^7$, then consider the (open) upper hemisphere, which is "star" convex with respect to the North pole.

Comment: Then $SO(7)$ is a $G_2$ bundle over $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^7$. Map an element of $SO(7)$ which lies over a point in the upper hemisphere to an element of the $G_2$ fibre over the North pole using parallel transport. But this is horribly not explicit. I kind of would like to do something similar, but more explicit, and easier to apply in practice. I don't know if what I am writing is clear enough or not...

Comment: @Malkoun:  I think I see what you want:  How's this?  Let $\times:\mathbb{R}^7\times\mathbb{R^7}\to\mathbb{R}^7$ be the cross product that $G_2\subset\mathrm{SO}(7)$ preserves.  Given a basis $v_i$ of $\mathbb{R^7}$ such that $v_3$ does not lie in the $3$-plane spanned by $v_1,v_2, v_1{\times}v_2$, let $e_1,e_2$ be the $GS$-orthonormalization of $(v_1,v_2)$ and write $v_3 = a\,e_1{\times}e_2 + b\,e_3$ where $b>0$ and $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ are orthonormal and complete to an orthonormal basis by setting $e_4 = e_1{\times}e_2$, $e_5=e_2{\times}e_3$, $e_6=e_3{\times}e_1$, and $e_7=e_6{\times}e_2$.

Comment: wonderful! This is what I wanted indeed. It is also easy to check. Thank you!

Comment: Now, I just need to tweak your construction a little, to make it Weyl-equivariant, but it would take me some time to explain what I mean. Anyway, you helped a lot! Thank you.

Comment: @RobertBryant, it has been two years since I wrote this post. I just wanted to tell you that what turned out to be relevant for my work is the subset of $GL(7,\mathbb{R})$ consisting of products $PG$ where $P$ is a symmetric positive definite element of $GL(7,\mathbb{R})$ and $G \in G_2$, where $G_2$ is thought of as a subgroup of $SO(7)$, itself a subgroup of $GL(7, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Does this subset form a subgroup? Maybe not, but I do not need it to be a subgroup actually, for my work. Note that it is the subset of matrices which have their orthogonal part under polar decomposition lie in $G_2$. I wonder if there is a more explicit way of describing it. There is a natural $W$-equivariant map from this subset to $G_2$, where $W$ is the Weyl group of $G_2$ (for some specific action of $W$ on this subset), and this is actually what I want.

Comment: @Malkoun:  It's definitely not a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(7,\mathbb{R})$, though it is a smooth submanifold (of codimension 7) that has a smooth retraction onto $\mathrm{G}_2$ (for example, just the restriction of the natural smooth retraction of $\mathrm{GL}(7,\mathbb{R})$ onto $\mathrm{O}(7)$).

Comment: Thank you Prof. Bryant. I think this may suffice for my purposes!